# how to check sql injection in this php code?

Tags: php, mysql

how do i check if this is vulnurable ?

```
function clean($str){
    return mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($str))));
}


if($_POST['submit']) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments(blog_id, dateposted, name, comment) VALUES
                (" . clean($validentry) . "
                , NOW()
                , '" . clean($_POST['name']) . "'
                , '" . clean($_POST['comment']) . "'
                );";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the `blog_id` using `is_int()` - because it is not wrapped in quotes, `mysql_real_escape_string()` won't be able to sanitize it. That is clearly a vulnerability.

Other than that, your code looks safe but it does a number of unnecessary sanitations.

`mysql_real_escape_string()` is completely enough for the `name` and `comment` fields.

The other calls are not necessary in that constellation; either `strip_tags` or `htmlspecialchars()` will do to protect against XSS attacks. However, it is regarded better practice to store the unsafe, raw HTML in the database, and sanitize it when outputting.

The `stripcslashes` call you can get rid of completely.

Comment: +1, but if the database schema has a minimal good design the `blog_id` will only accept / cast integers, I don't see how that can be considered a vulnerability.

Comment: @Alix `mysql_real_escape_string()` escapes only quote characters. It will *not* sanitize values like `1; (SQL code here)` that would get executed in the query

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that `mysql_real_escape_string()` doesn't add quotes like `PDO::quote()` does.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, did you code that function yourself? I'm asking because I keep seeing `clean()` and `makeAllSecure()` functions, each one worst than the previous.

To secure against SQL injections all you need to use is `mysql_real_escape_string()`, or similars.

Your `stripcslashes()` is also unnecessary, you might wanna call `stripslashes()` instead *iff* (as in **if and only if**) `magic_quotes` is `On` and `$str` is a user supplied variable, if the *iff* yields true this **should only occur once**, normally at the start of your script.

Regarding `strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($str))` - it only has the effect of converting `'`, `"`, `<` and `>` to their HTML entities notation, no tags will be stripped... If you really also want to strip tags what you are looking for is the following:

```
htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($str))
```

But this kind of sanitization should occur when you output HTML contents, not when you save in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

use these function for filtering query :
for example : this query ,you can not filtering if you not use the function below

http://www.example123.com/media.php?f=-1+OR+17-7%3d10

Parameter   Type    Value

f   GET     -1 OR 17-7=10

```
function clean($str){
    if(ereg('^[A-Za-z0-9]+$',$str)){
        $str=mysql_real_escape_string($str);
        return($str);
    }else{

       exit();
    }
}
```